# Pushing back an object to std::vector

Tags: c++, oop, object, vector, sfml

I'm coding a bullet system in c++. I'm not very experienced in c++.

For my bullet system, I want to have a bullet manager class, that updates and draws all the bullets. I also have a class called 'Bullet' that is well, a bullet.

```
class Bullet {
public:
    Bullet();

    sf::Sprite bullet_sprite;
    sf::Vector2f movement_vector;
    sf::Vector2f destination_pos;
    float speed;
};


class BulletManager : public Entity {
public:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    virtual void update(sf::RenderWindow& window);

    std::vector<Bullet*> bullets;

};
```

I store each bullet in a vector. In the draw and update functions, I run through this vector and perform the necessary operations on each bullet.

I'm having difficulties adding bullets to the vector from my *player* class. I'm trying to pass a reference to the new bullet like this:

```
bullet_manager.bullets.push_back(&bullet);
```

However, the size of the *bullets* vector always remains at zero.

How can I add new bullet objects to this vector from the player class?

Also - I have this in the player class since it is part of the 'handling player input' function.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I'd be careful with your design, as you are about one scope away from having a vector of dangling pointers.

Comment: if _bullets_ is still empty just after the `push_back` this means you have a serious memory corruption, and that may be because of the problem signaled by @CoryKramer. Create your bullet by a new rather than having it through typically a local variable in the stack

Comment: You are most likely modifying a copy of `bullets` or `bullet_manager`. Please double-check that you don't inadvertantly copy either. Otherwise, please show the `Player` class and the method in question.

Comment: I agree with @MaxLanghof - I seriously doubt that `bullets` appearing empty is due to memory corruption. Though I agree that using a `vector` of pointers like that is dangerous - Either make it a `vector<Bullet>`, either a `vector<std::unique_ptr<Bullet>>` if you need polymorphism.

Comment: Who must be the owner of this bullet? If the owner is the `BulletManager` class use `vector<unique_ptr<Bullet>>` as suggested by @Asu, otherwise double check the lifetime of your objects

Answer (score -1):

try using std::move()

check this link!

https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

and check this example from the link:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello";
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    // uses the push_back(const T&) overload, which means 
    // we'll incur the cost of copying str
    v.push_back(str);
    std::cout << "After copy, str is \"" << str << "\"\n";

    // uses the rvalue reference push_back(T&&) overload, 
    // which means no strings will copied; instead, the contents
    // of str will be moved into the vector.  This is less
    // expensive, but also means str might now be empty.
    v.push_back(std::move(str));
    std::cout << "After move, str is \"" << str << "\"\n";

    std::cout << "The contents of the vector are \"" << v[0]
                                         << "\", \"" << v[1] << "\"\n";
}
```